# Add Autoplay for tilted slider in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add autoplay for the tilted sliders. I am unable to add autoplay to slider. Here is the code.

```
TiltSlider.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this;
    // show a new item when clicking the navigation "dots"
    this.navDots.forEach( function( dot, idx ) {
        dot.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            if( idx !== self.current ) {
                self._showItem( idx );
            }
        } );
    } );
}
```

Comment: is TitleSlider your own component or could you please provide a link to it ?

Comment: It is not our own component

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TiltedContentSlideshow/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875841/adding-autoplay-prevnext-buttons-to-slider